# How does smart contract development differ between each of the EOS.IO side/sister chains?

Tags: smart-contract, mainnet, sidechain

Most tutorials that exist for smart contract development are directed at the EOS Mainnet chain. But there are several sister and side chains available, and the number is growing all the time. How does smart contract development change on each of these chains relative to the Mainnet?

I am especially interested in:

- Changes to syntax, code structure, ABI generation
- How resource management is handled
- New or different restrictions to things like transaction time, RAM controls, etc.
- References and links to appropriate information for each chain